Disk does not spin down for unknown reasons - How to debug?
I have a setup where we need to spin down HDDs that host a zfs array for energy reasons. I use hdparm to configure apm = 24 and spindown_time = 24 for all disks.
The system works as expected most of the times. The drives spin down after a few minutes of inactivity. However, from time to time, the disks do not spin down after a zfs recv.
I have been trying to find a way to debug this, but I haven't had luck so far. Here are a few things that I tried:

Run iotop to try to detect any file being written/read from the array. I was not able to detect any read or writes.
Run zpool iostat -v pool_name -r 60 to try to detect any read or write operations happening in the array. I monitored this output for almost an hour, and all the disks show zero operations for sync_read, sync_write, async_read, async_write, scrub, trim, or rebuild.

Is there any good way of debugging this problem?
Alternatively, do you have any hints of what may be happening? I think I have nailed it down to zfs as no read/write operations are happening, but I have no clue of where to continue looking.

I don't see any business relationship with this question or usual business practices. If you want to save energy, use an SSD. However, a lonely rotating disk with no access does use less power than an idle CPU.

Following up on the comments from @djdomi an idle spinning disk draws about 2.5 watts. Spinning it back up brings the usage to around 15 watts. An idle Xeon processor is pulling ~100 watts. Should you be concerned about the extra 2% savings you'd gain on spinning down the disks?

@djdomi I appreciate your concerns, but energy does add up if you have dozens of disks. This system has 36 disks, and there is a noticeable difference. Most of the data in this system is for replications that are not frequently accessible, so spinning down does make sense.
SSDs are not as cost efficient as HHDs, so swapping is not an option.

Could “from time to time” the disks still spin be because they are not being ‘used’ as such, but are still being processed or checked?

If you're looking to save energy, consider using a balcony solar system or a complete roof solar system. Many enterprise systems don't have support for spinning down, and even if you have a thousand devices, the issue is more about spinning them up and down, which can increase the likelihood of failure.

I think it is related to this @Hman66. I am just unable to see it with the zfs observability tools.
